# .NET GUI testing with JSystem

Tags: java, .net, user-interface, testing

Does somebody know a free tool, which can be easily integrated with jsystem to test .net based windows GUIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since JSystem is a Java framework, you can use the excellent [Twin](https://code.google.com/p/twin/) tool directly from your tests or to create a new system object that uses it.

Answer (score 0):

JSystem include integration with AutoIt (j2autoit.jar).